# How to Reorder/Reset auto increment primary key with foreign key?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables like below.

Person table with primary key and address table with primary key and the foreign key with the id of person table's primary key.

Both tables have missed some rows in between like 1,3,6....
some rows(4 and 5 ) have been deleted.

Now I need to rearrange primary keys in both tables and also after changing primary keys, foreign keys also need to be changes as to new primary keys.

please help.

Comment: It makes no difference that some id values are skipped over.  There is no (reasonable) *need* to re-assign the primary keys.  They should not be changed once they are set.

Comment: You shouldn't rearrange primary key. The best solution is, when you insert new data, add missed number as primary key.

Comment: That was a requirement which i wanted to do. This needs to do in a large two tables which has foreign key because of primary key column's data type (int) size is not enough and now we unable to change the data type also. Data is getting deleted in middle so time to time if we can rearrange, that will be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys should be NEVER changed for a record. Data consistency might broke than (new primary key could be non-unique, foreign keys might broke, etc).

This is basic rule for all relational databases.

Comment: Agreed. But this is a special requirement for large two tables with a foreign key and primary key column's data type INT. With current data growing, after some time INT type is not sufficient for the primary key column and if we can rearranged the column ids that will be solved the issue.

Comment: I highlight the word NEVER ;-). If INTEGER is not enough, use BIG_INTEGER (long) type.

Comment: Now that is impossible because it will effect for the entire system. That's why I'm searching alternate solutions.

Comment: Rearranging the PKs would affect the system even more.

Comment: Only issue is the foreign key in another table. Otherwise It won't effect for the system. If I'm able to solve foreign key issue(Change primary key with the foreign keys) that would be the best way.